# Validate email and password from an array of existing emails and passowrds in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, function, local-storage

I have two arrays **`emails`** and **`passwords`** (though you may see more) that I want to use to authenticate users during sign in. It's a practice issue not something to implement in the industry. See below:

[image: I am using the chrome browser database and the arrays can be seen on the right.]

The **other arrays** `checkEmails` and `checkPasswords` are not useful here but they act as a storage for even **failed** sign in's.
Onto the code I have a condition that authenticates using only a predetermined email and password. See below:

```
$("#myForm").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if ($("#inputEmail").val() != '' && $("#inputPassword").val() != '') {
    if ($("#inputEmail").val() == 'quis@google.com' && $("#inputPassword").val() == 'quis') {
      window.location.href = './database.html';
    } else {
      alert('invalid username password');
    }
  } else {
    alert('username or password cann\'t be blank');
  }
});
```

But now I want the authentication to search through the **`emails`** and the **`passwords`** arrays. 
Here is the whole ***userscripts.js*** file for **reference**.

```
$("#myForm").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if ($("#inputEmail").val() != '' && $("#inputPassword").val() != '') {
    if ($("#inputEmail").val() == 'quis@google.com' && $("#inputPassword").val() == 'quis') {
      window.location.href = './database.html';
    } else {
      alert('invalid username password');
    }
  } else {
    alert('username or password cann\'t be blank');
  }
});

const form = document.querySelector('form');
const input = document.getElementById('inputUsername');
const inputTwo = document.getElementById('inputEmail');
const inputThree = document.getElementById('inputPassword');
const ul = document.querySelector('ul')
const button = document.querySelector('button')

let usernamesArray = localStorage.getItem('usernames') ?
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('usernames')) : []

let emailsArray = localStorage.getItem('emails') ?
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('emails')) : []

let passwordsArray = localStorage.getItem('passwords') ?
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('passwords')) : []

let checkEmailsArray = localStorage.getItem('checkEmails') ?
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('checkEmails')) : []

let checkPasswordsArray = localStorage.getItem('checkPasswords') ?
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('checkPasswords')) : []

const liMaker = text => {
const li = document.createElement('li')
li.textContent = text;
ul.appendChild(li);
}

const liMakerTwo = text => {
const liTwo = document.createElement('li')
li.textContent = text;
ul.appendChild(li);
}

const liMakerThree = text => {
const liThree = document.createElement('li')
li.textContent = text;
ul.appendChild(li);
}
//let usernamesArray = []

localStorage.setItem('usernames', JSON.stringify(usernamesArray));
const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('usernames'))

//let emailsArray = []

localStorage.setItem('emails', JSON.stringify(emailsArray));
const dataTwo = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('emails'))

//let passwordsArray = []

localStorage.setItem('passwords', JSON.stringify(passwordsArray));
const dataThree = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('passwords'))

//let checkEmailsArray = []

localStorage.setItem('checkEmails', JSON.stringify(checkEmailsArray));
const dataFour = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('checkEmails'))

//let checkPasswordsArray = []

localStorage.setItem('checkPasswords', JSON.stringify(checkPasswordsArray));
const dataFive = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('checkPasswords'))

form.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
e.preventDefault()

checkEmailsArray.push(inputTwo.value)
localStorage.setItem('checkEmails', JSON.stringify(checkEmailsArray));

checkPasswordsArray.push(inputThree.value)
localStorage.setItem('checkPasswords', JSON.stringify(checkPasswordsArray));

usernamesArray.push(input.value);
localStorage.setItem('usernames', JSON.stringify(usernamesArray));

emailsArray.push(inputTwo.value)
localStorage.setItem('emails', JSON.stringify(emailsArray));

passwordsArray.push(inputThree.value)
localStorage.setItem('passwords', JSON.stringify(passwordsArray));
```

});

I attempted to replace `'quis@google.com'` with `emails array` and `'quis'` with `passwordsArray` but the authentication using this arrays failed. I have little experience with JS functions, arrays e.t.c that's why I am stuck. **Help** me out guys:-)
Here is the signin.html file just in case.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width", initial-scale="1">
    <title>Signin #DB</title>
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/primitive-ui/dist/css/main.css">
    <link href="css/signin.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body class="text-center">
    <form class="signin" id="myForm">
        <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Please Sign In</h1>
        <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email Address</label>
        <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" required autofocus>
        <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required><br>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign In</button>
    </form>
    <script src="js/userscripts.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Even though this is a practice issue, I would like to remind you that handling sensitive information, such as login, in a client side environment is a huge mistake. It's a literal candy store for hackers. Anyone can alter the logic by simply opening developer tools in their browser. The correct approach would be to handle simple validation (such as, is it a valid E-mail syntax etc.), actual username and password checks should be handled server side; outside of prying eyes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if your value (username and/or password) is included in an array by using [Array#includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

Example:

```js
var emails = ["email@email.com", my@email.com"]
var passwords = ["1234", 5678"]

emails.includes("email@email.com") // returns true
emails.includes("foo@bar") // returns false

passwords.includes("1234") // returns true
password.includes("an actual password") // returns false
```

So you can validate it doing something like this:
Just have in mind that the emails and passwords arrays are actually coming from your `localStorage`. You have to change it on this example.

```js
var isValidEmail = emails.includes($("#inputEmail").val())
var isValidPassword = passwords.includes($("#inputPassword").val())

if (isValidEmail && isValidPassword) {
  // Do something
} else {
  // Handle error
}
```